# How to append JSON data into an HTML element inside an AJAX call

Tags: json, jquery

I'm unsure how to append a Python value into an actual HTML element with JSON and AJAX. This is what I currently have, and below that is the ideal output as a list element. I'm not sure where to include the actual HTML element in the function. Currently it just spits out the unformatted data (obviously).

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "json",
  data: {'tag_title': tag_title, 'function': 'tag_add'},
  success: function(data) {

  $('.related-questions ul').html(data['question_title']); }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#">Why is the sky blue?</a></li>
```

Also, ideally I could chain multiple data in the success function into one HTML element, like...

```
<li><a href="#">Why is the sky blue?</a><span>14th December 2011</span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

in success function try:

```
alert($('.related-questions a').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you're just trying to get some html content for your page, try jQuery's `load()` function. Instead of sending json back to the browser, your python function could return simple "text/html".  For example:

HTML

```
<ul class="myContainer">
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$("ul.myContainer").load(myUrl, {'tag_title': tag_title, 'function': 'tag_add'});
```

HTML after:

```
<ul class="myContainer">
    <li>New Content with <b>whatever</b> tags you want</li>
</ul>
```

Look at .load() [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)